# JQuery Validation Remove Required Tag Temporarily

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

This is a MVC project that has a few text-boxes and a checkbox. When unchecked all of the text-boxes are required. When checked one of the text-boxes is disabled and not required, while the others remain required. The red border and the Required error message don't disappear with `.rules("remove","required")` I added some CSS to change the color of the border but I can't figure out how to get rid of the error message.

**Model View**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
public string textBox2{ get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
public string textBox3{ get; set; }
```

**Condensed Razor HTML**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.checkBox)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.textBox1, new { @class = "disabledTrue" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.textBox2)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.textBox3)
```

**CSS to disable red border, changes the color to lightgray**

```
.disabledTrue.input-validation-error:disabled {
    border-color:lightgray;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#textBox1').rules("add", "required");

    $('#checkBox').click(function () {
        //makes the input unrequired
        $('#textBox1').rules("remove", "required");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this. Works nicely. When the checkbox gets checked it is no longer required and the Required text is no longer shown. When it is checked it is required and the Required text is displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkBox').click(function () {
        if ($('#checkBox').is(":checked")) {
            //makes the input unrequired
            $('#textBox1').rules("remove", "required");
             //I added .disableRequired to my HTML 
             // I found .field-validation-error with firebug
             $("span.disableRequired.field-validation-error").css("display", "none");
        }
        else{
            //makes the input unrequired
            $('#textBox1').rules("add", "required");
             //I added .disableRequired to my HTML 
             // I found .field-validation-error with firebug
             $("span.disableRequired.field-validation-error").css("display", "normal");
          }
    });
});
```